# JobHost stopping randomly while running azure timer function app

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-function-app

I have  timer triggered azure function which runs in every 5 seconds. But Web Job Host is stopping in every 3/4 hour randomly for about 5 minutes and then start again.

I am not sure why? There is no exception/error in the logs.
Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: This is a question for [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Hello, I am not sure why ?

Comment: Because this question is about server administration, not programming

Comment: Could you provide the following information so we can investigate from back end?

- Function App version (1.0 or 2.0)
- Function App name
- Function name(s) (as appropriate)
- Region

If you don't want to give your function app name, you can do so privately.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately